# Can a class be renamed programmatically?

Tags: python, class

I have `Vehicle` class. I want to rename it to `Rover`. I know we can create another reference variable, but I don't want the name of the class to be same anymore.

Played with `__name__`, but no success.

```
class Vehicle:
    pass
st="Rover"
Vehicle.__name__=st
obj1=Rover()
```

Expected:
`Vehicle` class renamed to `Rover` without file handling and within the program.

Comment: Would inheritance be better here? Changing the fundamental name of your class is going to break a lot of dependent code no?

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: Yes definitely but it's like after a particular portion of my code is executed if I rename that class and associated sub-classes to be used in some other file I can save a lot of work.

Comment: What kind of situation are you finding yourself in where this would save work? If you explain the context, we can probably suggest a better option. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: What you are trying to do is very far from best practice. If you want to chance the class name, change your code.

Comment: Assigning to the class's `__name__` is absolutely not going to cause the existing global variable `Vehicle`, that refers to the class, to change *its* name...

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html] ```This provides semantic for importing and renaming``` I read this and so I thought renaming can be done and didn't find any link to help me with that so asked this question while preparing a simple vehicle class with 2,3 wheelers cost, type, premium amount etc as attributes. The thought of changing the name to Rover and use the attributes as it is.

Comment: Rex5: Sounds to me like `"Rover"` should be the string _value_ of a `Vehicle` class instance _attribute_: e.g. `vehicle1.model`. Folks often confuse the two...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, you have a (very slightly mangled) quote from https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html:

> This provides semantic for importing and renaming

Here's the actual quote, with a bit more context:

> As in Smalltalk, classes themselves are objects. This provides semantics for importing and renaming.

What this is talking about is the fact that we can have a Python library with a class in the library:

```
# lib_k.py
class Klass:
    ... definitions ...
```

Then, in some other Python module, we can write:

```
from lib_k import Klass as LibKClass
```

which is mainly useful if we're also going to do:

```
from lib_l import Klass as LibLClass
```

and then write code like:

```
def f(args):
    obj_k = LibKClass(...)
    obj_l = LibLClass(...)
```

I personally prefer to write:

```
import lib_k
import lib_l

def f(args):
    obj_k = lib_k.Klass(...)
    obj_l = lib_l.Klass(...)
```

but both ways are allowed, and which to use is something of a matter of taste, rather than correctness.

Comment: `import`ing a class and giving it a different local name like that does not change the actual class object. i.e. `print(LibKClass.__name__)` -> `Klass` and `print(LibLClass.__name__)` -> `Klass`. Also, module names (and therefore their corresponding file names) should be all lowercase (according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names)), so I would suggest avoiding the use of them here in example code (because it could give newbies the wrong idea).

Comment: @martineau: good point, I'll rename them to `lib_k` and `lib_l` here. I thought about mentioning the fact that the `__name__`s remain unchanged, but decided to stop at this point.

Comment: torek: That's better...and you don't need to mention not changing `__name__` — I've done it for you down here in the comments. `;¬)`